# interrogation point (question mark) instead of citation call-out

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I have a problem with the citation in winedt .When I put \cite and compile the code I find interrogation point in pdf generated .
The winedt does not show any error but he show a 3 warnings

[image]

This is the code guy's

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[squaren, Gray, cdot]{SIunits}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{graphicx}

 \begin{document}
     bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \cite{ben_mot_dies}

     \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
     \bibliography{mot}
 \end{document}
```

Also this is the bib_text :

```
@MASTERSTHESIS{ben_mot_dies,
  author =       {Benarfaoui.B},
  title =        {Etude du moteur Diesel},
  school =       {Université
        de Mohamed Kheider Biskra},
  type =         {Mémoire fin d'étude},
}
@book{cleynen2015thermodynamique,
  title={Thermodynamique de l'ing{\~A}{\copyright} nieur},
  author={Cleynen, Olivier},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Lulu. com}
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You need to run BibTeX on your document, so that you end up with a LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX cycle for. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864